# Finding integration factor

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Could someone verify if the integrating factor for the differential equation is $e^x$ and whether it makes the DE exact or not.

$$\dfrac {dx}{dt} = \dfrac {(-x + e^t)}{(t - xt + e^t + e^x)}$$

**My attempt:**
$$Mdx+Ndt=0$$
 I rearranged the DE to get $N(t,x) = x - e^t$ and $M(t,x) = t - xt + e^t + e^x$ and differentiated $N$ wrt $t$ and $M$ wrt $x$. then did $(N' - M')/M$ to get 1 and integrated wrt $x$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Can you show what you have done so far in the body of your question?

Comment: There is a sign difference so it seems it's not exact

Comment: As im unsure how to format, I rearranged the DE to get N(t,x) = x - e^t and M(t,x) = t - xt + e^t + e^x and differentiated N wrt t and M wrt x. then did (N' - M')/M to get 1 and integrated wrt x

Comment: Are you sure it's not $e^{-x}$ that is needed ?

Comment: The integrating factor should be $e^{-x}$ not $e^x$. I also posted your attempt in your question. Thats what you should always do. Post question and attempt toegether. Otherwise it's deleted or closed.

Answer (score 1):

You made a little mistake for the integrating factor:
$$Mdx+Ndt=0$$
Differentiate $M$ wrt $t$ and $N$ wrt $x$:
$$\frac 1 {\mu}\frac {d \mu }{ dx}={\color {red}{\frac {M_t-N_x}N}} $$
$$\frac {d \mu }{\mu}=\frac {1-x+e^t-1}{x-e^t} dx$$
$$\frac {d \mu }{\mu}=-dx$$
$$\ln \mu =-x \implies \mu(x)=e^{-x}$$